# What exactly triggers this service worker code to run?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Create-react-app comes with a registerServiceWorker.js file that contains code to register a service worker.  I'm just a bit confused as to how it works.  The code in question is:

```
function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
        .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
            }    
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:',     error);
    });
}
```

What needs to happen for that first console log, the one that displays "New content is available; please refresh," to display?

More specifically, how can I trigger this code to run when index.html changes (in the event that a script filename changes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break it down step by step.

1. `navigator.serviceWorker.register` Promise is resolved when the valid Service Worker existence has been established
2. `registration.onupdatefound` registers a listener for an event that is fired when the HTTP request for Service Worker has been resolved to some other file than previously (or when the SW has been found for the first time)
3. `registration.installing.onstatechange` registers a listener for the new Service Worker's lifecycle changes (from installing to installed, from installed to activating etc.)
4. `if (installingWorker.state === 'installed')` filters out all the states other than `installed` - so its positive branch will be executed after each new SW has been installed
5. `if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller)` checks if the page is currently controlled by any (previous) Service Worker. If true then we're handling the aforementioned update scenario here.

So summing up - this `console.log` will execute after the updated (not the first one) Service Worker has been correctly installed.

It will not be triggered after `index.html` change. It's only Service Worker code (pointed to by `serviceWorker.register` method) that is checked against. Note also that normally browsers (or Chrome at least?) do not check for the new SW version for 24h after the current one was downloaded. Note also that plain old HTTP cache set for the Service Worker file might mess up here if it was send with too aggresive cache header.

Comment: Great explanation.  So I'm going about this the wrong way?  How would I achieve the desired result of detecting a change in in `index.html`?

Comment: Either don't use cache-first approach for your index.html or ensure your sw.js gets updated every time index changes. Or better think about applying App Shell architecture so you don't need to change your index.html that often.

Comment: So am I reading that `registration.onupdatefound` only runs when a whole new filed is registered as the service worker? Not if changes are made to the previously used file?
Or what was that about "version changes" every 24 hours? Is that saying that it's cached and the cache expires every 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, correct. `onupdatefound` means a whole new Service Worker file was found. It can happen not earlier than 24h from the last time because of that threshold.